# canOpenURL succeed but openURL fails, for tel as urlschema

Tags: ios, swift, url-scheme

My App is like this:

User Enters phone number in one textField. App Saves it. Then it displays the phone number in detail screen which has "Call" button. I call `canOpenURL` method and if succeeds, then i keep my call button enabled, otherwise keep it disabled.

I am creating URL with format like this : `tel:phone number`.

Now, one of my tester added phone number = '55'. Now, when i am calling `canOpenURL`, then it is getting success, but when i call `openURL` method, it is not showing popup for phone number.

This one is working perfectly fine for other phone numbers, even 2 digit phone numbers like = 13, but for some specific phone numbers like 55,56 it getting failed.

NOTE: As per my client's requirement, i dont have to put any validation on phone number, like it must have n number of characters or so. So, please dont provide answers like this. I required the reason why canOpenURL is getting success and openURL getting failed.

Answer (score 1):

The function `canOpenURL` will only check if the schema is valid, i.e. there is an app installed that will handle the URL. 
It does not say that the *resource* is valid, in your case, that the `number`is valid. See  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl

The problem with *55* being invalid is - as I see it - caused by the specification of the `tel` URLScheme in [RFC 2806](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2806.txt). 
I copied some relevant parts:

```
telephone-url         = telephone-scheme ":"
                        telephone-subscriber
telephone-scheme      = "tel"
telephone-subscriber  = global-phone-number / local-phone-number
global-phone-number   = "+" base-phone-number [isdn-subaddress]
                        [post-dial] *(area-specifier /
                        service-provider / future-extension)
base-phone-number     = 1*phonedigit
local-phone-number    = 1*(phonedigit / dtmf-digit /
                        pause-character) [isdn-subaddress]
                        [post-dial] area-specifier
                        *(area-specifier / service-provider /
                        future-extension)
...
area-specifier        = ";" phone-context-tag "=" phone-context-ident
```

As I read the EBFN, the `telephone-subscriper` always starts with either a `+` or a `1` character.

Further on, in `2.5.2 Phone numbers and their scope`, the RFC says:

```
If a <local-phone-number> is used, an
<area-specifier> MUST be included as well.
```

In my opinion, this is the reason why tel:55 fails, but tel:13 is ok.

Comment: As per you, the number 25, 29 etc should not work, numbers starting with only 1 or 0 should only work. whereas i tried different numbers and i found this: 1. all 3 digit phone numbers work, 2.  for case of 1 and 2 digit phone numbers, those starting with 0,1 or 2 works, others dont work

Comment: This is strange. As I interpret the RFC, you could either use a *global* numer (which starts with a `+` character) or a *local* number which always requires a *context*, i.e. something like `;phone-context=` at the end of the URI. Maybe only Apple knows what they did...